# Bash insert config with special characters into wp-config.php

Tags: wordpress, bash, replace, sed, scripting

I'm trying to insert a config used to get the (presumably) real IP of visitors to our sites, into their respective wp-config.php, but I'm running into issues with the large number of special characters involved.

I plan on adding this to a bash script that spins up new Wordpress installs quickly, but as it is I have to go in and manually add the line after each install.

This is the config...

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = preg_replace('/^([^,]+).*$/', '\1', $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']);
```

A snipit of the wp-config.php:

```
$table_prefix = 'wp_';

define('WPLANG', '');



/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */
```

I originally thought I could insert the config in the whitespace under "define('WPLANG', '');" with sed as I've done with other similar tasks...

```
find="define('WPLANG', '');"
replace="$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = preg_replace('/^([^,]+).*$/', '\1', $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']);"

sed "s/$find\n\n/$find\n$replace/"
```

...but the special characters are throwing everything off.  I've tried numerous different ways of quoting and escaping but I'm not having any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily do this with awk:

```
awk -vrep="$replace" '{print}/define.*WPLANG/{print RS rep}' wp-config.php
```

This prints every line unconditionally. When a line containing "define" and "WPLANG" is matched, it also prints the value of the shell variable `$replace`, with a newline before it.

In order to avoid problems with escaping characters in bash, you can use `cat` with a HEREDOC:

```
replace=$(cat <<'EOF'
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = preg_replace('/^([^,]+).*$/', '\1', $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']);
EOF
)
```

The single quotes around `'EOF'` mean that the characters in the string are interpreted literally.

Comment: I had to escape the parentheses, but it works perfectly nonetheless. Thank you